# Qt VTK real-time point cloud rendering

Tags: c++, qt, qml, vtk

I am working on real-time point cloud rendering project in Qt Quick and VTK. I have a laser sensor with sampling rate of 200Hz. For testing the program generates random points in while loop using QtConcurrent::Run.

Here is my code:

**pointcloud.h**

```
#ifndef POINTCLOUD_H
#define POINTCLOUD_H

#include "QQuickVTKRenderItem.h"
#include "qtconcurrentrun.h"
#include "qtmetamacros.h"
#include "vtkActor.h"
#include "vtkMath.h"
#include "vtkPolyData.h"
#include "vtkPolyDataMapper.h"
#include "vtkSmartPointer.h"
#include <QObject>
#include "vtkDoubleArray.h"
#include "vtkPointData.h"
#include "vtkRenderWindowInteractor.h"
#include "vtkSmartPointerBase.h"
#include <math.h>
#include <QTimer>
#include <QtConcurrent>
class PointCloud : public QObject {
  Q_OBJECT
public:
  explicit PointCloud(QObject *parent = nullptr);
  void setVtkItem(QQuickVTKRenderItem *item);
  Q_INVOKABLE void addPoint(const double point[3]);
  Q_INVOKABLE void clear();
  Q_INVOKABLE void startRandom();


private:
  vtkSmartPointer<vtkPolyData> polyData;
  vtkSmartPointer<vtkActor> actor;
  vtkSmartPointer<vtkPoints> m_points;
  vtkSmartPointer<vtkDoubleArray> depth;
  vtkSmartPointer<vtkCellArray> vertices;
  vtkSmartPointer<vtkPolyDataMapper> mapper;
  QQuickVTKRenderItem *m_renderItem;


signals:
};

#endif // POINTCLOUD_H
```

**pointcloud.cpp**

```
#include "pointcloud.h"
#include "vtkProperty.h"
#include "vtkSmartPointer.h"

PointCloud::PointCloud(QObject *parent)
    : QObject{parent}{
  polyData = vtkSmartPointer<vtkPolyData>::New();
  mapper = vtkSmartPointer<vtkPolyDataMapper>::New();
  vertices = vtkSmartPointer<vtkCellArray>::New();
  depth = vtkSmartPointer<vtkDoubleArray>::New();
  depth->SetName("depth");
  m_points = vtkSmartPointer<vtkPoints>::New();
  polyData->SetPoints(m_points);
  polyData->SetVerts(vertices);
  polyData->GetPointData()->SetScalars(depth);
  polyData->GetPointData()->SetActiveScalars("depth");
  mapper->SetInputData(polyData);
  mapper->SetColorModeToDefault();
  mapper->SetScalarVisibility(1);
  actor = vtkSmartPointer<vtkActor>::New();
  actor->SetMapper(mapper);
  actor->GetProperty()->SetPointSize(2);

}
void PointCloud::setVtkItem(QQuickVTKRenderItem *item) {
  m_renderItem = item;
  if (m_renderItem) {
    m_renderItem->renderer()->AddActor(actor);
  }
}
void PointCloud::addPoint(const double point[3]) {
  auto pid = m_points->InsertNextPoint(point);
  depth->InsertNextTuple1(point[2]);
  vertices->InsertNextCell(1);
  vertices->InsertCellPoint(pid);
  m_points->Modified();
  depth->Modified();
  vertices->Modified();
}

void PointCloud::clear() {
  vertices->Initialize();
  vertices->Modified();
  depth->Initialize();
  depth->Modified();
  m_points->Initialize();
  m_points->Modified();
}
void PointCloud::startRandom(){
  auto future=QtConcurrent::run([&](){
    while(polyData->GetPoints()->GetNumberOfPoints()<1000000){
      auto theta=2*vtkMath::Pi() *vtkMath::Random();
      double phi=acos(2*vtkMath::Random()-1);
      double p[3]={sin(phi)*cos(theta),sin(phi)*sin(theta),cos(phi)};
      addPoint(p);
      Sleep(5);
    }
  });
}
```

**main.cpp**

```
#include "pointcloud.h"
#include <QGuiApplication>
#include <QQmlApplicationEngine>
#include <QQuickVTKRenderItem.h>
#include <QQuickVTKRenderWindow.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
  QQuickVTKRenderWindow::setupGraphicsBackend();
  QGuiApplication app(argc, argv);
  PointCloud cloud;
  qmlRegisterType<QQuickVTKRenderWindow>("VTKPLUS", 9, 1, "VTKRenderWindow");
  qmlRegisterType<QQuickVTKRenderItem>("VTKPLUS", 9, 1, "VTKRenderItem");
  qmlRegisterSingletonInstance<PointCloud>("PointCloud", 1, 0, "PointCloud",
                                           &cloud);
  QQmlApplicationEngine engine;
  const QUrl url(u"qrc:/VTKTest/main.qml"_qs);
  QObject::connect(
      &engine, &QQmlApplicationEngine::objectCreated, &app,
      [url](QObject *obj, const QUrl &objUrl) {
        if (!obj && url == objUrl)
          QCoreApplication::exit(-1);
      },
      Qt::QueuedConnection);
  engine.load(url);
  QObject *rootObject = engine.rootObjects()[0];
  auto *container = rootObject->findChild<QObject *>("container");
  auto *renderItem = container->findChild<QObject *>("renderItem");
  QQuickVTKRenderItem *vtkRenderItem =
      dynamic_cast<QQuickVTKRenderItem *>(renderItem);
  vtkRenderItem->renderer()->SetBackground(1, 1, 1);
  vtkRenderItem->update();
  cloud.setVtkItem(vtkRenderItem);

  return app.exec();
}
```

**main.qml**

```
import QtQuick
import VTKPLUS
import VTKTest 1.0
import PointCloud
import QtQuick.Controls
import QtQuick.Controls.Material
import QtQuick.Layouts

ApplicationWindow {
    visibility: "Maximized"
    visible: true
    title: "VTK Test"
    menuBar: MenuBar {
        Menu {
            id: fileMenu
            title: 'Files'
            Action {
                text: "Add Point"
                onTriggered: {
                    PointCloud.startRandom()
                }
            }
            Action {
                text: "Clear"
                onTriggered: {
                    PointCloud.clear()
                }
            }
        }
    }
    Item {
        anchors.fill: parent
        objectName: "container"
        VTKRenderWindow {
            objectName: "vtkRenderWindow"
            id: vtkwindow
            anchors.fill: parent
        }
        VTKRenderItem {
            objectName: "renderItem"
            anchors.fill: parent
            renderWindow: vtkwindow
        }
    }
}
```

The code works but when adding new points, the vtk scene updates are very slow.

Comment: Hi Is there a tutorial I can follow the implemenation from ?

Comment: @AdityaG for what?

Comment: I mean how to integrate VTK  into a QT framework !

Comment: @AdityaG you can take a look at vtk documentation https://vtk.org/doc/nightly/html/classQQuickVTKRenderItem.html